# delegates after migrating .Net 1.1 project to 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I've migrated a .Net legacy .Net project from .Net 1.1 to .Net 3.5 and when I try and run it I'm getting the following error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control 'grpLogin' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

When the a thread (Which I assume is not the UI thread) changes the enabled property of a button to true.

I reckon something changed in the framework to add this restriction, is there a way to make this work without overhauling the entire app?

Can I make VS (I'm using VS 2008)run the App as .Net 1.1 (I'm not even sure that this is the problem)

The application is merely a test application for an API which I've been told to reverse engineer, so and I don't really have the bandwidth to fix all it's issues. I know it worked previously but I don't have an old version of VS installed so I had to convert it over to VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

The fix isn't to use anonymous methods: it's just to use `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke` in *some* way. It doesn't matter whether it's an anonymous method, a delegate created from a method group or a lambda expression - the point is that you need to marshal over to the UI thread. See [my threading article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml) for more details. You might also want to consider using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to make it easier. (My article was written before .NET 2.0, hence its lack of BackgroundWorker references.)

This was already a bug in your 1.1 code, by the way - this isn't a new restriction in .NET 2.0, it's just that .NET 2.0 added a check (throwing the exception you've seen) when running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Found Fix [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/447970ba-1384-4b07-9566-395dad9db90d/) solution is to use annonomous delegates:

```
 // running on worker thread...
  string newText = LongRunningOperation();

  //switch to UI thread
  this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    // this bit runs on the UI thread
    this.Text = newText;
  });
```

Obviously replace "this.Text" with whatever code you want to run in UI thread, works a charm.

Still interested in a way to run as .Net 1.1 under VS 2008 I heard that you can run multiple F/Work versions in it, just don't know how.

I've started addign the annonomous delegates to anywhere there is UI code to fix this issue.